# Spring-boot integration test, set request attribute for TestRestTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, mocking, integration-testing

I am setting request attribute called `Id` in prehandle method of `RequestHandlerInterceptor`. I get this id from jwt token.

```java
 protected UserContext getCurrentUserContext() {
        return UserContextHolder.getCurrentContext();
 }

 @Override
 public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws AuthenticationException {
        UserProfile userProfile = null;
        try {
            UserContext userContext = getCurrentUserContext();
            userProfile = userContext.getUserProfile();         
            request.setAttribute("Id", String.valueOf(userProfile.getId()));
            return true;
        }
```

using `@RequestAttribute` in my controller method to get this attribute.

```java
@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
public void delete(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestAttribute("Id") String userId) throws EntityNotFoundException, ApiException {
        excessService.deleteExcess(id, userId); 
}
```

But my integration tests are failing though I've overridden this `RequestHandlerInterceptor`.

```java
    requestHandlerInterceptor = new RequestHandlerInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws AuthenticationException {
            request.setAttribute("Id", "123456");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

How can I mock this request attribute in integration test, to pass that 'id' value into my controller methods?